# How many injective functions $f: A \to B$ satisfy $f(a_1) = b_1$ or $f(a_2)=b_2$?

Tags: combinatorics, functions, discrete-mathematics, relations

I've been stuck on this question for hours, and am having trouble trying to start this question. If anyone could help, that would much appreciated.

The question is Let $A = \{a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4\}$ and $B = \{b_1, b_2, b_3, b_4, b_5\}$ (where $|A| =4$ and $|B|=5$), how many injective functions $f: A \to B$ satisfy $f(a_1) = b_1$ or $f(a_2)=b_2$?

Comment: What have you tried?  For instance, do you know how to calculate the number of injective functions $f: A \to B$?

Comment: Just count them. A function on finite sets are simply ways you can match up ordered pairs. To be a function each term in A must map to a term in B. To be injective each term in A must map to a distinct term of B. We are told a1 maps to b1 and a2 to a2. We only have to figure out the way to map a3 and a4 to b3, b4, b5. There are only so many ways to do that. If I had a second pinky, I could count them on the fingers of one hand.

Answer (score 1):

Define $F_1 = \{f\colon A\to B | f(a_1) = a_1, f \text{ injective} \}$. Define $F_2$ similarly for $f(a_2) = b_2$. Then use the fact that functions in $F_1$ are injective to find the cardinality of $F_1$ and similarly for $F_2$. Once you've done this, find the cardinality of $F_1 \cap F_2$. Then the total number of injective functions $f\colon A\to B$ satisfying $f(a_1) = b_1$ or $f(a_2) = b_2$ is $|F_1| + |F_2| - |F_1 \cap F_2|$ by the inclusion exclusion principle.

Answer (score 1):

Case 1: $a_1$ is mapped to $b_1$

There are four ways to map $a_2$; to $b_2, b_3, b_4,$ of $b_5$.

There are three ways to map $a_3$.  (To any of the three remaining values).

There are two ways to map $a_4$.  (To any of the two remaining.)

That's 24 ways.

Case 2:  $a_1$ is not mapped to $b_1$

Then $a_2$ must map to $b_2$.

There are three ways to map $a_1$; to $b_3, b_4, b_5$

After $a_1$ and $a_2$ are mapped; there are three remaining ways to map $a_3$.

After $a_1, a_2,$ and $a_3$ are mapped there are two remaining ways to map $a_4$.

That's $18$ ways.

That's $24 + 18 = 42$ ways.  I'm going to need a lot more pinkies.

Comment: It seems to me that you are counting the number of injective functions that satisfy $f(a_1) = b_1$ *and* $f(a_2) = b_2$, but we need to find the number of injective functions that satisfy $f(a_1) = b_1$ *or* $f(a_2) = b_2$.

Comment: Oh, you're right.  Well, that's still exceedingly easy and straightforward.